# Regarding measurable functions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space and let $f:X\to \mathbb R$ and $g:X\to \mathbb R$ be mesurable functions. Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$. We want to show that $\{x\in X:(f(x),g(x))\in G\}$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable.

Since $f,g$ are $\mathcal A$-measurable, therefore, $f^{-1}((c,\infty)),g^{-1}((c,\infty))\in \mathcal A$ for all $c\in \mathbb R$. Now how to relate these things with $G$? Any hint will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h=(f,g):X\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and define
$$
\mathcal{C}:=\{B\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2\mid h^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{A}\}.
$$
Then show that

1. $\mathcal{C}$ is a sigma-algebra in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
2. $\{(a,\infty)\times (b,\infty)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$
3. Conclude that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\subseteq\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the functions $f: X\rightarrow G \cap \mathbb R $ and $g: X \rightarrow  G \cap\mathbb R$. And use that open subsets are measurable (in the standard measure on $\mathbb R$), and so is their intersection with $\mathbb R$. Then $\{x\in X:(f(x),g(x))\in G\}=f^{-1}(G \cap \mathbb R ) \cup g^{-1}(G \cap \mathbb R)=f^{-1}(G) \cap f^{-1} (\mathbb R) \cup f^{-1}(G)\cap \mathbb R $. But $G$ is open, and $f$ is measurable, so that $f^{-1}(G)$ is measurable, and so the union is measurable.